# Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 28

Tags: jmeter

From jmeter I am trying get URL http://dot4ap-mms-cr:8080/fms/Kernel/w_login.jsp
I have this error: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 28

Somebody can give a help please.

PB

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your config elements and samplers. Also share the configurations you have made for your URL in HTTP Request.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the whole URL into "Server Name or IP" box. It's better to configure your [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) as follows:

- Server Name or IP: `dot4ap-mms-cr`
- Port Number: `8080`
- Protocol: `http`
- Path: `/fms/Kernel/w_login.jsp`

  [image: HTTP Request Configuration]

---

In the most recent JMeter versions i.e. [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) you can put the whole URL into `Path` input like:

[image: HTTP Request Path Configuration]

But I don't really like this approach, and prefer using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) instead.